# Integral evaluation taking too long

Tags: performance-tuning

When I try to evaluate the following integral, it runs for a much longer time than I think is should without producing a result. What might be the problem? Can anybody please point it out?

```
h[s_, t_] := HeavisideTheta[s] HeavisideTheta[t - s]
Integrate[Abs[(b*(1 - e^((-b)*s)))/b - h[s, t]], {s, 0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Granting the beginner's mistake of confusing `e` with `E` (not really the culprit here), let's look at your integrand:

```
Simplify[Abs[(b*(1 - e^((-b)*s)))/b - h[s, t]]]

(* ==> Abs[1 - e^(-b s) - HeavisideTheta[s] HeavisideTheta[-s + t]] *)
```

it becomes clear that the integral over $s$ to $\infty$ is not convergent for $b\neq 0$. So you should go back and check your math. When you encounter such integration problems, it's a good idea to test the expression for some reasonable numerical choice  of the parameters (`b` and `t` in particular)!

In this case you perhaps confused multiplication by the `HeavysideTheta` terms with subtraction.

Because I'm guessing that this is a math error on the user end, I'm proposing to close this question as too localized.

Comment: It may still be good to have an answer here, since people who encounter similar problems should be encouraged to do some sanity checking before posting to StackExchange...

Comment: well, thank you for your response, but i evaluated the integral by hand too, and there is no problem, it is convergent. I am trying to find out what is wrong with the mathematica code. I am correcting e -> E, however, i am not following your comment on heavisidetheta

Comment: @jens Are you sure about convergence? I'm not on my pc so can't check this, but I believe the integral converges for positive b.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The integrand goes to `1` outside the unit box, so it doesn't converge.

Comment: @NoLeafClover Of course I can't really guess what your goal is. But the step functions have no effect for `s > t`, and the remaining terms don't go to zero, so the infinite integral goes to infinity.

Comment: $$\int_0^t |1-e^{-bs}|ds + \int_t^{\infty}e^{-bs}ds$$
 
 and this is equal to $t+ \frac{2}{b}e^{-bt}- \frac{1}{b}$

that is, integral is convergent. It is a pretty simple integral actually, i am just incapable of doing this with mathematica, and i have to do it with mathematica for the next step, which is impossible to do by hand.

Comment: @NoLeafClover I think you swapped the integration limits in your last comment (so as it is the integral is not convergent).

Comment: Ah, I missed the constant 1 term. The exponential itself converges.